# React Native Picker - Styling selector to not be grey

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, picker

I am trying to style the selector background in the picker component, Where there is the grey background in the picture below. I am trying to change it to a white background and have a border around it.

[image: selector]

```
   <Picker
        selectedValue={selectedProject}
        onValueChange={(text) => {
          setSelectedProject(text as string);
        }}
        style={{
          width: '50%',
          alignSelf: 'center',
        }}
        itemStyle={{
          height: 200,
        }}>
          <Picker.Item key={'all'} label={'all'} value={'all'} />
          <Picker.Item key={'all1'} label={'all1'} value={'all1'} />
          <Picker.Item key={'all2'} label={'all2'} value={'all2'} />
   </Picker>
```

I have tried everything - which makes me think it cannot be done.

I have tried adding `backgroundColour` / `colour` properties to the `style` and `itemStyle` of the `Picker` component but neither of those works.

Is it possible to style this grey selection box?

Comment: Can you inspect what is being done to the element itself as rendered html and write some css in a stylesheet to override that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the issues in [react-native-picker](https://github.com/react-native-picker/), there is a [talking](https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker/issues/165) about the customizing the selected item inside the picker.

More over, **it is not possible to do so at present**, as the native properties for the selection indicator styles aren't bridged over yet.

The code inside [RNPicker.m](https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker/blob/master/ios/RNCPicker.m#L27) file should be modified to handle the customization.

```
[self selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES]; // Workaround for missing selection indicator lines (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564660/uipickerview-selection-indicator-not-visible-in-ios10)
```